# Radio button is Selecting multiple items Instead of selecting one item

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, radio-button

[image: List of all Roles]

I am using input type radio like below

```
<input type="radio" id={el.name} className="form-check-input" name={el.name} data-count={el.name} value={el.id} onChange={this.select_role.bind(this)} style={{margin: "4px 10px"}}/>{el.name}
```

OnChange function looks like Below

```
 select_role(event){
    console.log(event.target);
    let attribute = document.getElementById(event.target.name);
    let sectorattrribute = attribute.getAttribute("data-count");
    this.setState({role_id : event.target.value, roleName: sectorattrribute})
  }
```

The output of above type radio is

[image]

OnChange Console lokks like Below
[image: OnChange Console looks like Below]

Radio should allow only one item to be selected but why I can able to select multiple at a time and I am unable to deselect also.

But as per radio type doc once, one item is selected other gets deselected but it is happening.

Please guide me where I am doing the mistake.

[![enter image description here][4]][4]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set same name field to all radio buttons ,Try this

**Example**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <body>

     <form action="">
       <input type="radio" name="role" value="male">Admin<br>
      <input type="radio" name="role" value="female">Agent<br>
      <input type="radio" name="role" value="other"> Director
      <input type="radio" name="role" value="manager">Manager
       <input type="radio" name="role" value="client">Client
      <input type="radio" name="role" value="super admin">Super Admin
         <input type="radio" name="role" value="admin 1">Admin 1
          <input type="radio" name="role" value="admin 2">Admin 2
     </form>

     <p><b>Note:</b> When a user clicks on a radio-button, it becomes checked, and all 
     other radio-buttons with equal name become unchecked.</p>

     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: Name should not be unique?
Based on name I am making one more select statement. so can't we make with name unique

Comment: If I give same Name its working but based on name i am validating other select statement so can't we make with unique name

Comment: please show the code ,where you are validating by name

Comment: I have given id attribue  unique and name same still getting same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173524/discussion-between-taha-sultan-temuri-and-user9883888).